# Properly handling a 2-dimensional array of values within a recursive function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm implementing a custom function in Apps Script.

To allow the function to be used as an array formula in Google Sheets, I'm using the following template for the function:

```
function myfunction(input) {
  if (input.map) {                // Test whether input is an array.
    return input.map(myfunction); // Recurse over array if so.
  } else {
    // Handle individual values here...
  }
}
```

Doing so allows the custom function to accept a range as input in the form of a two-dimensional array, then returns a two-dimensional array that can overflow into the appropriate cells. [This is documented here.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#optimization)

However with the code below, I'm not using "input", I'm using "url" which I believe is the source of my problems. I produces the error: `Attribute provided with no value: url (line 5)`.

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  if (url.map) {
    return url.map(getRedirect);
  } else {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': false});
    var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location']; // undefined if no redirect, so...
    var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
    if (redirectUrl) {                                   // ...if redirected...
      var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect(redirectUrl);    // ...it calls itself recursively...
      Logger.log(url + " is redirecting to " + redirectUrl + ". (" + responseCode + ")");
      return nextRedirectUrl;
    } else {                                               // ...until it's not
      Logger.log(url + " is canonical. (" + responseCode + ")");
      return url;
    }
  }  
}
```

What could I do to fix this?

Comment: I cannot understand about `I'm not using "input" I'm using "url"`. So can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? And if you want to use `getRedirect()` as the custom function, also can you provide the formula you tested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suspicion is that you're not properly handling values that are not valid URLs. Assuming there's not more to your script, line 5 contains the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call, which I believe is the source of the error.

You should perform additional error checking before and during the `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` call. Here's an modified implementation demonstrating what I'm suggesting:

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  if (url.map) {
    return url.map(getRedirect);
  }

  // Return an empty string if url contains a non-string value or an empty string.
  if (typeof url != 'string' || url == '') {
    return '';
  }

  // Enclose the UrlFetchApp.fetch() call in a try/catch() block...
  try {
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        'followRedirects': false,
        'muteHttpExceptions': false
    });
  } catch(e) {
    // And return an empty string if the call fails
    // (e.g. if provided a non-empty, non-URL string).
    return '';
  }

  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (redirectUrl) {
    var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect(redirectUrl);
    return nextRedirectUrl;
  }
  return url;
}
```

A few notes:

- Perform as much error checking as possible before the `try`/`catch` block. It's much faster to handle invalid input before calling `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. Calling the `fetch` method and waiting for it to fail can take a noticeably longer time, especially if you're processing a large range.
- I removed the logging statements to make the example a tiny bit more succinct, but it may be prudent to log error conditions and/or return strings that call out the errors as opposed to empty strings.
- The name of variable is irrelevant (i.e. `input` vs `url`)
- I removed superfluous `else` blocks, as `return` statements end execution of the function anyway.

Comment: awesome thanks so much chuckx, thanks for not only helping me with this issue but explaining everything super clearly, I'm incredibly grateful

Comment: Feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).